# How do I install a Windows XP-only compatible program in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, installation

How do I install a Windows XP-only compatible program in Windows 7? Can I use Windows XP compatibility mode?

Answer (score 4):

### Some options

1. Right-click on the executable and
   select **Properties** and go to the
   **Compatability**  tab. Select the option to run it in XP compatability
   mode.

   [image: Compatibility mode]
2. If you have Windows 7 Professional
   or better, you can try running it in
   [XP-mode.](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/download.aspx)
3. If you don't have the Professional
   version or for some other reason
   can't use XP-mode, but have a
   non-OEM Windows disk lying around,
   you can download the free
   [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) and use it through
   that. Unfortunately, it's not quite
   as seamless as Virtual PC.

Answer (score 3):

Probably, see http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windows-7/features/windows-xp-mode.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Most (not all) programs work just fine in a new version of Windows. The gray area is when you get into hardware or very specific in depth windows operations. The the more expensive versions of Win 7 comes with an XP virtual machine that make sure that programs run good.